# Scala: type alias with object

Tags: scala

I often want to avoid new class creation in scala by using type aliases. But I also need some static methods for those types.
Consider following example for CardValue type:

```
package object cards {
  /**
   * Type representing card values from 2 to A
   */
  type CardValue = Byte
}

object CardValue {
  /**
   * Creates CardValue
   *
   * @param value value index from 0 (2) o 12(A)
   * @tparam T any Numeric type which can be converted to Byte
   * @return new CardValue
   */
  def apply[T <% Byte](value: T): Card = {
    require(value >= 0 && value < 13, "Wrong card value index. CardValue is enumeration from 0 to 12.")
    value
  }

  /**
   *
   * @return Correct string for card value
   */
  override def toString: String = {
    case 8 => "T"
    case 9 => "J"
    case 10 => "Q"
    case 11 => "K"
    case 12 => "A"
    case x: Number => (x.byteValue() + 2).toString
  }
}
```

There are currently two issues with this code:
1. it doesn't compile
2. I'm not sure that code will work as i planned (for example that it will call toString from object and not from Byte).

Am I doing this all in the wrong way, and type aliases can't be used like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really what type aliases are for. When you declare `type CardValue = Byte`, `CardValue` shouldn't be an actual type. Using that syntax, `CardValue` would literally be the `Byte` type, except for the name, so you wouldn't be able to override it's methods or anything--unless you extended it to another class.

The other problem with this code is that the `toString` method should be in a class, not an object. `object CardValue` should probably be a companion object to `case class CardValue(value: Byte)`, and you could define `toString` there.

```
case class CardValue(value: Byte) {

    require(value >= 0 && value < 13, "Wrong card value index. CardValue is enumeration from 0 to 12.")

    override def toString: String = this.value match {
        case 8 => "T"
        case 9 => "J"
        case 10 => "Q"
        case 11 => "K"
        case 12 => "A"
        case x: Number => (x.byteValue() + 2).toString
    }

}
```

Comment: this works, thanks and it answers all my questions. Also, you need to remove object implementation. Case classes come with default apply method

Comment: You're right. I'll move your `require` to the case class where it belongs.